# how to get maple to do linear algebra in Z_2 (integers modulo 2)

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, maple

how to get maple to do linear algebra in Z_2    (integers modulo 2)

I don't want it to solve and then reduce mod 2 I want it to work over Z_2  so basis([  [1,1,1], [1,-1,1 ]) = [1,1,1]

If this is not the right stackexchange site to ask this please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

The Maple help page with topic [LinearAlgebra,details](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=LinearAlgebra/Details) mentions the [Modular](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=LinearAlgebra%2FModular) subpackage in the 5th bullet point of the Description section.